# Getting the pid of a job launched in the background remotely

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to launch in the background a job on a remote machine and get its PID so that I can kill it later on. What I have come up with so far is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
REMOTE_EXEC="ssh $IP -l root"

# The following does NOT work, I am trying to get the PID of the remote job
PID=`$REMOTE_EXEC 'vmstat 1 1000 > vmstat.log & ; echo $!'`

# Launch apache benchmark
ab -n 10 http://$IP/

$REMOTE_EXEC "kill $PID"
```

Unfortunately it does not work. I am getting a

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

but I don't know what the right syntax would be.

Comment: Simply:

`vmstat 1 1000 > vmstat.log & ; echo $!`

doesn't even locally. Take a look at it.

Comment: Yes I know. So I either need a fix for 'vmstat 1 1000 > vmstat.log & ; echo $!' or I need to get the PID of the remote job through some other mechanism.

Comment: @davitenio Doesn't PID end up as the PID of the local ssh command, not the remote vmstat command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the error, because you ';' is redundant, try 'vmstat 1 1000 > vmstat.log & echo $!'

But I am not sure it gonna work, because after you logout, the process will receive SIGHUP. Look at nohup(1).

Comment: Yeah, you are right...
May be, it happens, because in this case ssh does not "login" you (from ssh(1): "If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.").

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding the backgrounded command in curly braces:

```
PID=`$REMOTE_EXEC '{ vmstat 1 1000 > vmstat.log & }; echo $!'`
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use weak quoting, you need to escape $! like the following:

```
$REMOTE_EXEC "{ vmstat 1 1000 > vmstat.log & }; echo \$!"
```

or

```
P=`$REMOTE_EXEC "{ vmstat 1 1000 > vmstat.log & }; echo \\\$!"`
```

Comment: I am getting
-bash: !": event not found
with 
ssh host "{executable & }; echo \$!"

Comment: It may depend on your OS. It perfectly works on Ubuntu 12 and higher. If you're using weak quoting, try to escape ! symbol too as described here http://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found  or don't use weak quoting.

Comment: I found the problem - it was that "history expansion" was enabled. If I used that line inside of a script, it worked correctly, but if I ran it directly from a terminal, it failed. If I turn off history expansion with 'set +H', then it works properly from the terminal.